# React/Jest/Enzyme - await not waiting long enough

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jestjs, enzyme

I have a function that awaits multiple promises

```
const function = async () => {
    await function1()
    await function2()
    await function3()
}
```

I want to test that function3 is called:

```
it(('calls function3', async () => {
    jest.spyOn(api, 'function1').mockResolvedValue({})
    jest.spyOn(api, 'function2').mockResolvedValue({})
    spy = jest.spyOn(api, 'function3')
    await function()
    expect(spy).toBeCalledTimes(1)
})
```

and this test fails, but when I call await a lot of times:

```
it(('calls function3', async () => {
    jest.spyOn(api, 'function1').mockResolvedValue({})
    jest.spyOn(api, 'function2').mockResolvedValue({})
    spy = jest.spyOn(api, 'function3')
    await await await await await function()
    expect(spy).toBeCalledTimes(1)
})
```

the test will pass. Why is this? Shouldn't `await function()` resolve all of the promises before moving onto the next expect line?

edit: The deeper the awaited function is i.e. a function4, the more await statements I need, but its not 1 to 1.

Comment: `function` is a javascript reserved word, are you sure your function declaration does not throw any error?

Comment: @Dario sorry this is an example and not actual code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a matter of the order that the promises are enqueued in the micro-task queue, I'm using [`flush-promises`](https://github.com/kentor/flush-promises) to resolve the same issue.

It uses nodes `setImmediate` that pushes to the queue a callback that will be called when the micro-task queue is empty.

```
const flushPromises = require('flush-promises');

test('flushPromises', async () => {
  let a;
  let b;

  Promise.resolve().then(() => {
    a = 1;
  }).then(() => {
    b = 2;
  })

  await flushPromises();

  expect(a).toBe(1);
  expect(b).toBe(2);
});
```

Comment: Is there a solution that doesn't require importing another library?

Comment: This lib is 9 lines of code :], you can copy it to your project.

Answer (score 8):

> Shouldn't `await function()` resolve all of the promises before moving onto the next expect line?

Yes, `await` will wait for the returned `Promise` before continuing.

Here is a simple working example:

```
const function1 = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue();
const function2 = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue();
const function3 = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue();

const func = async () => {
  await function1();
  await function2();
  await function3();
}

it('calls function3', async () => {
  await func();
  expect(function3).toHaveBeenCalled();  // Success!
})
```

---

If `await` is not waiting as long as expected, then the `Promise` chain is likely broken at some point.

Here is an example of a broken `Promise` chain:

```
const function1 = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue();
const function2 = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue();
const function3 = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue();

const func = async () => {
  await function1();
  await function2();
  await function3();
}

const func2 = async () => {
  func();  // <= breaks the Promise chain
}

it('calls function3', async () => {
  await func2();
  expect(function3).toHaveBeenCalled();  // <= FAILS
})
```

Calling `await` multiple times will queue the rest of the test function at the back of the [`PromiseJobs`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-jobs-and-job-queues) queue multiple times which can give pending `Promise` callbacks a chance to run...

...so the broken test above will pass if it is changed to this:

```
it('calls function3', async () => {
  await await await await func2();  // <= multiple await calls
  expect(function3).toHaveBeenCalled();  // Success...only because of multiple await calls
})
```

...but the real solution is to find and fix where the `Promise` chain is broken:

```
const func2 = async () => {
  await func();  // <= calling await on func fixes the Promise chain
}

it('calls function3', async () => {
  await func2();
  expect(function3).toHaveBeenCalled();  // Success!
})
```

Comment: The promise chain breaks when it awaits a synchronous function?

Comment: No, a `Promise` chain breaks if `await` isn't called on a `Promise` that should be part of the chain.  In the example the `Promise` returned from `func` is chained to the `Promises` returned from `function1`, `function2`, and `function3`...but `func2` **doesn't** call `await` on `func` so the `Promise` returned from `func2` isn't chained to the other `Promises`.  Fixing `func2` to call `await` on `func` fixes the chain and ensures that the `Promise` returned from `func2` is chained all the way through to the `Promise` returned by `function3`.  @peter176

Answer (score 1):

By now there is a [proposal in Jest](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2157) having something like `runAllTimers` but for promises.

So if you'd like to avoid integrating `flush-promises` you may just use `setTimeout(() => {...rest code...}, 0)`. Since `timeout` is macrotask it's guaranteed all pending microtasks(like promises) are resolved before running that.

More on microtasks and macrotasks: https://abc.danch.me/microtasks-macrotasks-more-on-the-event-loop-881557d7af6f