# Typescript cannot log after tests are done. Did you forget to wait for something async in your test?

Tags: typescript, promise, jestjs

I have this `async` function `resolveProps` which traverse through all nested schema of a given jsonschema (if any) and give me all props in a tree hierarchy

```
import * as _ from "lodash";
import { loadSchema } from "../loader"; 

 export type SchemaData = {
  filename: string;
  schemaStorage: SchemaStorageMode;
  isRoot: boolean;
  schemaPath: string;
};

const resolveProps = async (schemaData: SchemaData): Promise<object> => {
  let schemaObj = {};
  // just for e.g.
  schemaObj = {
    child_data: {
      allOf: [
        { $ref: "child_schema_1.json" },
        { type: "object" },
      ],
    },
    ip: {
      allOf: [
        { type: "string" },
        { format: "ipv4" },
      ],
    },
    user: { type: "string" },
    pwd: { type: "string" }
  };

  _.map(schemaObj, async (value, key) => {
    
    const childSchema = await Promise.all(
      generatePaths(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value)), "$ref") // [{"values":"child_schema_1.json"},{"values": ""},{ "values": ""},{ "values": ""}]
        .filter((o) => 
          o.values.includes(".json");
        )
        .map((o) => 
          o.values;
        )
        .map((e) =>
          resolveProps({
            ...schemaData,
            filename: e
          })
        )
    );

    if (!_.isEmpty(childSchema))
     return _.set(
       schemaObj,
       [key],
       _.reduce(childSchema, (acc, e) => ({ ...acc, ...e }))
      )
    else 
      return _.set(schemaObj, [key], value);
  });

  return schemaObj;
};

export { resolveProps };
```

And this is how I am calling it from `testcase`.

```
test("validates data successfully", async () => {
  const schemaData: SchemaData = {
    filename: "tc_multilevel_schema_top.json",
    schemaStorage: SchemaStorageMode.FileBased,
    isRoot: true,
    schemaPath: path.join(__dirname, "..", "..", "..", "public", "artifacts"),
  };

  const res = await resolveProps(schemaData);

  // expect(res).toBe({some json object});
});
```

This works fine without promise , but with promise which eventually I want , not getting the desired `res`. If I console anything inside my `resolveProps` I am getting `cannot log after tests are done. Did you forget to wait for something async in your test?` But its actually consoles the right fulfilled data.

I am guessing missing some basic of `promise` implementation here.

To evaluate `jest` for `async function` I tried below sample `testcase` and that worked fine

```
import { promises as fs } from "fs";
import * as path from "path";

export const loadJsonFromFS = async (filename: string, filepath: string) => {
  return JSON.parse(await fs.readFile(path.join(filepath, filename), "utf8"));
};


test("validates data successfully", async () => {
  const res = await loadJsonFromFS(
    "tc_multilevel_schema_top.json",
    path.join(__dirname, "..", "..", "..", "public", "artifacts")
  );
  expect(res).toEqual({some data});
});
```

Comment: try `expect(resolveProps(schemaData)).resolves.toBe({something})` or swap `toBe` with `toEqual`

Comment: I dont think so the problem is with `jest` , its basically with the `resolveProps` . It always gives me the initial `schema` data and never returns the `nested promise fulfilled` sub-schemas . In my view if I do `const res = await resolveProps(schemaData)` from anywhere it should give me all resolved data . but that's not happening

Comment: [take a look at this answer or the whole post itself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56566554/6611487)

Comment: I tried `jest` with a simple `async function` , its working fine . So I am  pretty sure its something `promise` related issue only with `resolveProps`

Comment: "*Did you forget to wait for something async in your test?*" - well yes you did. Nothing waits for the array of promises created by `_.map(schemaObj, async (value, key) => {…})`.

Comment: My understanding was `_.map(schemaObj, async (value, key) => {…})` this is inside `resolveProps` and hence in my test   `const res = await resolveProps(schemaData);` this should take care of all `Promises` .

Answer (score 1):

I am able to resolve it by wrapping the `recursive part` under a `await` , when analyzed the issue , figured out everything under `recursive part` was getting fulfilled post the test execution , so it make sense to add `await` there and that fixed the issue

```
await Promise.all(
    _.map(schemaObj, async (value, key) => {
       .....
      })
    )
```